# Google App Engine Permalink page

Tags: python, google-app-engine, permalinks

I am trying to build a simple blog application to use the skills that I learned from Udacity so far. However, I am having trouble retrieving data from the database and displaying it for the user. Now, my blog has a permalink which displays the post that was just being submitted by the user, and also the main blog page which will display the latest 10 posts in descending order. But when I submit a post, the post is stored in the database successfully, and I am being redirected to a permalink. However, all I get is a 404 error page.

Here's the main Python code:

```
import os
import re
import webapp2
import jinja2
from string import letters
from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

def render_post(response, post):
    response.out.write('<b>' + post.subject + '</b><br>')
    response.out.write(post.content)

def post_key(name = "dad"):
    return db.Key.from_path('blog', name)

class Blogger(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.TextProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

    def render(self):
        self._render_text = self.content.replace('\n', '<br>')
        return render_str("post.html", a = self)

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Visit our blog")

class BlogHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        posts = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Blogger order by created desc")
        self.render("frontblog.html", posts = posts)    

class SubmitHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("temp.html")    
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get("name")
        content = self.request.get("content")
        if name and content:
            a = Blogger(parent = post_key(), name = name, content = content)
            a.put()
            self.redirect('/blog/%s' % str(a.key().id()))
        else:
            error = "Fill in both the columns!"
            self.render("temp.html", name = name, content = content, error = error)        

class DisplayPost(Handler):
    def get(self, post_id):
        po = Blogger.get_by_id(int(post_id), parent = post_key())
        if po:
            self.render("perma.html", po = po)   
        self.response.write("No")     



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                              ('/blog', BlogHandler), 
                              ('/blog/submit', SubmitHandler),
                              (r'/blog/<post_id:([0-9]+)>', DisplayPost)], debug=True)
```

Here's the HTML code for the base of all the HTML pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />

  <title>CS 253 Blog</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/blog" class="main-title">
    CS 253 Blog
  </a>

  <div id="content">
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the HTML code for the permalink page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  {{po.render() | safe}}
{% endblock %}
```

HTML code for the front of the blog:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% for p in posts %}
    {{ p.render() | safe }}
    <br><br>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

What seems to be the problem with my permalink code?

EDIT 1:

Including the yaml file:

```
application: deploymentapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: 404 means your handler could not be found. Which link do your use and check your app.yaml

Comment: I am checking it on my local server on port 8080. I am also including the yaml file in my original post. Have a look. Also, I have also deployed my app on the internet. Check out http://www.deploymentapp.appspot.com/blog/submit      After submitting our content, we should be redirected to a permalink page. However, we get a 404 error

Comment: You use a simple route to handle the DisplayPost. You have to use an extended route, because you use keywords: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#extended-routes

Comment: Finally the permalink is working! Thanks a lot. By the way, I don't really get what you mean by 'keywords' in this case. Can you elaborate more on the same?

Comment: You use the keyword argument '<post_id:', which is not possible in simple routes. So skip the keyword to make it a simple route: (r'/blog/(\d+)>', DisplayPost) or use a extended route.